# Map $z^2=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{ \frac{1}{2}-it },t\in\mathbb{R}$ maps the real axis $(-\infty,\infty)$ onto the unit circle $\mid z\mid=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration, mobius-transformation

> Show that the mapping
> $$
> z^2 = \frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{1}{2}-it}, \quad t\in\mathbb{R}
> $$
> maps the real axis $(-\infty,\infty)$ to the unit circle $|z|=1$.

**My try-**
$$z^2=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{ \frac{1}{2}-it  }$$
$$|z^2|=\frac{|\frac{1}{2}+it|}{ |\frac{1}{2}-it|  }$$
$$|z^2|=\frac{\sqrt{1/4+t^2}}{  \sqrt{1/4+t^2} }$$
$$|z^2|=1$$
$$|z|^2=1$$
$$|z|=1$$...

Comment: Looks good. Do you have to show if it's bijective?

Comment: @Sean Nemetz No i have to onlu show that it maps real axis to unit circle

Answer (score 1):

The map is *multivalued* as $z^2=1$ at $t=0$ gives $z=\pm 1$ lying on unit circle $\lvert z\vert=1$.

**Added 1-**The partial proof you have done shows that the map is onto. But it cannot be a bijection as it is not a single valued function.

**Added 2-** For another proof, note that

$t=\frac{z^2-1}{2i(z^2+1)}$, where $z=x+iy, x,y\in\mathbb R$
After splitting the RHS into real and imaginary parts, you can equate the imaginary part of $RHS=0$ (*Why?*) to get the result $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: So will it map the real axis to unit circle?

Comment: Why are we considering t=0?

Comment: Isn't the real axis has equation $t=0$ as per the language of problem?

Comment: Yes but how does t=0 has to do something with showing it maps to the unit circle?

Comment: I will give you a check mark. Please answer.

Comment: @Anandita.... I made an edit. Now see.

Comment: Can you please give me other proof of the fact that is maps the real axis to unit circle. Please.

Comment: If we define$$ w=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{1}{2}-it}}$$ then is w bijective?

Comment: It depends on the choice of definition like $\sqrt{a}$ symbol stands for positive square root of a real number $a$ conventionally.

Comment: So which is the most appropriate definition? Note that under square root we have complex terms

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why did you equate the imaginary part of RHS to 0?

Comment: As $t\in\mathbb R$ so it must be free from $i$.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure! Always welcome in this platform of two-way learning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120049/discussion-between-anandita-k-and-nitin-uniyal).

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Please Prove that this map is onto. I will give you a check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You argument is partially correct. You did show that $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ into a subset of the unit circle, but the problem requires to show the entire unit circle is covered by the image. In other words, if you look at $f:\mathbb{R} \to D_1(0)$, it would be onto (surjective).

To do this, let $z \in D_1(0)$ and show that there is $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t)=z$.

Comment: How to show it is surjective?

Comment: Please give a complete proof.

Comment: I will give you a check mark. Please answer.

Comment: Can you please give me other proof of the fact that is maps the real axis to unit circle. Please.

Comment: If we define$$ w=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{1}{2}-it}}$$ then is w bijective?

Comment: Please Prove that this map is onto.

Comment: @AnanditaK People here are generally not fond of doing your problems for you when you do not exhibit any effort in solving the problem. I am happy to teach you something, but to do that I need to see you are trying something, either based on my hints or not... what have you tried? do you know what *onto* means in this context? where specifically are you getting stuck in that proof?

Answer (score 0):

Let the unit circle be $z=e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Then,

$$t= \frac1{2i} \frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1} = \frac1{2i} \frac{e^{i 2\theta}-1}{e^{i 2\theta} +1} =\frac12\tan\theta
$$
which reveals that $\theta\in[0,\pi)$ and $\theta\in[\pi,2\pi)$ separately map to $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$, thus, not bijective.

Comment: Why are we checking for bijectivity?. Can't we have a map that is not injective?

Comment: @AnanditaK - no need to check. Just an observation.

Comment: What are the implications of the map not being injective? Is it an issue?

Comment: @AnanditaK - it is not a problem if not required

Comment: Please Prove that this map is onto.